# Am I supposed to let PG know in advance before I back up its datadir?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I run PostgreSQL on Windows. Its data dir is located in "My documents". I often back up that entire dir tree (among others) with ROBOCOPY, which "robustly" copies the dir tree to local and external disks.

Since PG is running at the same time as my ROBOCOPY script, I just had the idea that maybe this is not safe? Should I "let PG know" that I'm about to back up/copy its data dir, and then let it know when I'm done? Or is that unnecessary? Maybe even not a "thing" at all?

It strikes me that it could theoretically be bad if PG is writing to its database files while ROBOCOPY is also copying the same files. But maybe this has been solved fully 30 years ago and I'm just still stuck in early 1990s computing thinking.

I *also* (separately) use `pg_dump` regularly. The idea of shutting down PG entirely many times a day is not an attractive one.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a usable online file system backup, you have to do one of the following:

- Run `pg_basebackup` with `-X stream` (the default in later versions). That will do everything for you.
- If you want to use this Robocopy, you have to use the low-level API:

  - enable WAL archiving by setting `archive_mode` and `archive_command` to archive WAL segments (you might use Robocopy there)
  - run `SELECT pg_start_backup('label');` to get the database into backup mode
  - backup the data directory with Robocopy
  - end backup mode with `SELECT pg_stop_backup();`

  To recover, you wilk have to use `restore_command`

  Note that I showed you the comparatively simple deprecated "exclusive backup", the "non-exclusive backup" is somewhat more complicated.

Consult the documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-file.html)

> The database server **must** be shut down in order to get a usable backup.

Another option is to use `pg_dump`.

That quote is still valid today. If you want real incremental backups (not dumps) then you need you use [WAL archiving](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) or use a tool like barman, `pgbackrest`, or `pg_probackup`.

See [What is a database backup](https://blog.dbi-services.com/what-is-a-database-backup-back-to-the-basics/).

Answer (score 0):

Any decent rdbms can and -my opinion- should be backed up online.

One of the reasons is exactly this, going for a filesystem backup with the database down. What happens if during that backup the database is started? It invalidates the backup and you only detect the problem at restore time.

An other reason is because it gives more options to restore and recover to any point in time(hoping that tx logs are backed up quick enough)

If you go for a filesystem backup:

1. Inform the rdbms that a backup will be taken
2. Perform the filesystem backup
3. Inform the rdbms that the backup is ready

Make sure to test the restore if the data has any value.

Better is to use the supplied tools to make the database backup. Those tools will try to tell you what is needed to get it done right and in many cases refuse to backup if the result would become unusable.